# Radio Button Group Form Helper Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, radio-button, formbuilder

I have a model, pointofinterest, that has_many pictures. I want to be able to select one thumbnail image for each pointofinterest in my database to use throughout my website.

The problem is that my radio buttons are not acting like a radio button group. It allows me to select more than one radio button when my form is generated.

I have tried using just radio_button instead of picture.radio_button and it associates them as being in a group. Am I missing something here?

```
<%= f.fields_for :pictures do |picture| %>
    <% unless picture.object.new_record? %>

    <%= link_to( image_tag(picture.object.photo.url(:thumb)), picture.object.photo.url(:original) ) %>

    <div class="checkbox inline">
        <%= picture.label :destroy%>
        <%= picture.check_box :_destroy %>

        <%if :pictures[0] == picture %>
            <%= picture.label :thumbnail, :value => true%>
            <%= picture.radio_button :thumbnail, 'thumbnail', :checked => true %>
        <% else %>
            <%= picture.label :thumbnail%>
            <%= picture.radio_button :thumbnail, 'thumbnail', :checked => false %>
        <%end%>

    </div>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

EDIT - Full _form partial:

```
    <%= form_for(@pointofinterest, :html => { :multipart => true }) do |f| %>
  <% if @pointofinterest.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@pointofinterest.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this pointofinterest from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @pointofinterest.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :description %>
    <%= f.text_area :description %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :latitude %>
    <%= f.text_field :latitude %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :longitude %>
    <%= f.text_field :longitude %>
  </div>

  <div class="">
    <%= f.fields_for :pictures do |picture| %>

        <% if picture.object.new_record? %>

            <%= picture.file_field :photo %>

        <%end%>

    <% end %>
</div>

<div class="existingPaperclipFiles">
    <% @pointofinterest.pictures.each do |picture| %>
        <% unless picture.nil? %>
        <%= link_to( image_tag(picture.photo.url(:thumb)), picture.photo.url(:original) ) %>
        <div class="checkbox inline">
            <%= f.check_box :_destroy %><%= f.label :Delete%>
            <% checked = (@pointofinterest.thumbnail_id == picture.id) ? "true" : "false" %>
            <%= f.radio_button :thumbnail_id, 'thumb', :checked => checked %> <%= f.label :Thumb %>
        </div>
        <%end%>
    <% end %>
</div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Submit"%>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to use `fields_for` for this

`fields_for` is for another model - I think you're wanting to select the `:thumbnail_id` attribute in your "parent" model:

```
#app/models/point_of_interest.rb
Class PointOfInterest < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :pictures
    belongs_to :thumbnail, class_name: "Picture"
end

#app/models/picture.rb
Class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :point_of_interest
    has_many :points_of_interest, class_name: "PointOfInterest", foreign_key: "thumbnail_id"
end

#app/views/controller/action.html.erb
<%= @pictures.each do |picture| %>
    <%= link_to( image_tag(picture.object.photo.url(:thumb)), picture.object.photo.url(:original) ) %>

    <div class="checkbox inline">
        <%= f.label :destroy%>
        <%= f.check_box :_destroy %>

        <% checked = (@original.thumbnail_id == picture.id) ? "true" : "false" %>
        <%= f.label :thumbnail_id %>
        <%= f.radio_button :thumbnail_id, 'thumbnail', checked : checked %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Rich. I should let it be known that I'm trying to do this in /views/pointofinterests/_form.html.erb. I have posted my full code along with the edit that you suggested. The good news is, my radio buttons are now acting as a group. I have added the thumbnail_id attribute to the pointofinterests table in my database.  Now I would like to be able to save the picture's id into the pointofinterest thumbnail_id when the submit button is clicked. Being new to rails, I would greatly appreciate the help, thanks!